# How to retrieve Metadata Type component fields?

Tags: metadata

I am referring to the Metadata Type documentation, for example [Custom Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm).

Is there a way to get all the 'fields' available for the Custom Object (or any other) Metadata Type, for example:

- actionOverrides
- allowInChatterGroups
- businessProcesses
- compactLayoutAssignment
- ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [describeMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_describe.htm) to get a full list of all metadata, and then call [describeValueType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_describeValueType.htm) to get the specific fields for each (e.g. allowOverrides, etc). This is actually how some IDEs and integrations that deal with deployments, etc, allow dynamic integration with metadata.

Comment: Awesome! it works! Thanks!